# Mysql didn't get perfect result in Android Application

Tags: android, mysql

[image: This one is Frist Image List of College (Mysql Search)]

**First Image u can see List of college.
When i clicked first college i got perfect result
when i clicked last college i didn't get Result..plz help**

here
1)ListCollege.java//First Activity it's give me list of College//First Image

```
    collegelist=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.collegeList);
    InputStream is = null;

    String result = "";
     //the year data to send
     ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("searchcollege",search_college));
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("searchcity",search_city));

     //http post
     try{
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.career4u.org/android/android_connection.php");
             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
             is = entity.getContent();

     }catch(Exception e){
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
     }

     //convert response to string
     try{
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
             String line = null;
             while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                     sb.append(line + "\n");
             }
             is.close();
             result=sb.toString();
             String result1[]=result.split("\\}\\,\\{");
             for(int i=0;i<=result1.length;i++)
             {
                     result1[i]= result1[i].replace("[{", "").replace("institue_name", "").replace("\"", "").replace("}]", "").replace(":", "");
                     collegelist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , result1));  
                     collegelist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                              int position, long id) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(ListCollege.this,viewCollege.class);
                            intent.putExtra("search_college", ((TextView) view).getText());
                            startActivity(intent);
                         }
                        });
             } 

     }catch(Exception e){
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
     }
     //parse json data
}
```

}

2)viewCollege.java//Second Activity it's give me information of college//second and Third Image

```
    String search_college =getIntent().getExtras().getString("search_college");
    collegeName.setText("    "+search_college);

    InputStream is = null;

    String result = "";
     //the year data to send
     ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("searchcollege",search_college));


     //http post
     try{
             HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
             HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.career4u.org/android/android_collegeDetail.php");
             httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
             HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
             HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
             is = entity.getContent();

     }catch(Exception e){
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
     }

     //convert response to string
     try{
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
             StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
             String line = null;
             while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                     sb.append(line + "\n");
             }
             is.close();
             result=sb.toString();
             **collegeAddress.setText(result);//Display Mysql Result in JSON**
             //String result1[]=result.split("\\}\\,\\{");
             //for(int i=0;i<result1.length;i++)
             //{
              //     result1[i]= result1[i].replace("[{", "").replace("institue_name", "").replace("\"", "").replace("}]", "").replace(":", "");
             //} 

     }catch(Exception e){
             Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
     }

}
```

}

[image: click on First College]

[image]

Comment: Use [`EntityUtils.toString(HttpEntity)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/util/EntityUtils.html#toString(org.apache.http.HttpEntity)) instead of rolling your own with `BufferedReader`/`StringBuilder` -- less code and it obeys the character encoding sent by the server.

Comment: Also, don't roll your own JSON parser! Use the built-in [`JSONObject`](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) or one of the other libraries like Gson, Jackson, etc.

Comment: And assuming from the call to `findViewById()`, you're doing network IO in the UI thread (`onCreate()` etc.) --- **don't do this!** Android will force close your app once it runs on a real device with real-world network speeds and response times. Use an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead -- do your HTTP in `doInBackground()` and then update your UI from `onPostExecute()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this part of yout code:

```
     for(int i=0;i<=result1.length;i++)
     {
             result1[i]= result1[i].replace("[{", "").replace("institue_name", "").replace("\"", "").replace("}]", "").replace(":", "");
             collegelist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , result1));  
             collegelist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                      int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(ListCollege.this,viewCollege.class);
                    intent.putExtra("search_college", ((TextView) view).getText());
                    startActivity(intent);
                 }
                });
     }
```

You are Overriding the adapter and itemclicklistener of all items while looping

```
collegelist.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 , result1));
collegelist.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()...
```

First what you need to do is save the result in result1 parsing it. After the loop Override the adapter , you must program the onclicklistener , using the arrayData to know which item is (with the position) are you clicking in .

Maybe it can be easy for you to have an auxiliar array to do it.